# C# - Invalidate() and Update()

Tags: c#, graphics, paint, invalidation

Can you help me with this piece of code ?
I want to learn to use Invalidate and Update , but I'm not sure how to use it
This code doesn't work. I want set new text but it doesn't "refresh" and doesnt write the new string "Prova". Thanks

```
namespace Invalidate
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private String txt;
    private PointF xy;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("This is the text that prints!",
        this.Font, System.Drawing.Brushes.Azure, 0, 0);
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel pHText = new Panel();
        pHText.Name = "ctrId"; 
        pHText.Location = new Point(10, 10);
        pHText.Size = new Size(200, 200);
        pHText.BackColor = Color.White;
        pHText.Paint += paintingUrCtr;
        Controls.Add(pHText);
    }

    private void paintingUrCtr(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Font myFont = new Font("Arial", 14);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 0, 0, 10, 10);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.txt, myFont, Brushes.Blue, 10, 10);
    }
    public void setText(String text, PointF pos)
    {
        this.txt = text;
        this.xy = pos;
    }
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setText("Prova", new PointF(100, 100));
        this.Invalidate();
        this.Update();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please include an error message and explanation of expected vs. actual behavior

Comment: HI , This code doesn't write the new string "Prova"  when I click on push button

Comment: You are invalidating the form, not the panel.  Minimize your form then restore it to see your text.

Comment: OK when I minimize the form it works. How do I invalidate the panel in order to change text everytime I click on push button ?Thanks

Comment: Since you created the control locally to the load event, you would have to find it in the control's collection: `this.Controls["ctrId"].Invalidate();`

Comment: Thanks so much LarsTech !!, it works ! :))

Comment: _"I want to learn to use Invalidate and Update"_ -- no, not really, you don't. Knowing how to use `Invalidate()` is well and good, but you should not be using `Update()` or its siblings `Refresh()` and `Application.DoEvents()`. These are all hacks to work around code that was written wrong in the first place. If you have long-running operations that could potentially interfere with the immediate updating of your program's UI, those operations should be executed asynchronously. There are lots of possible ways to do this, but see `Task.Run()`, `async`, `await`, and `Progress<T>` to start with.

Comment: I will do , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Calling `this.Invalidate();` does not invalidate child controls, you need to use the overload [that takes in a bool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz8ytzt0(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass in `true`

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    setText("Prova", new PointF(100, 100));
    this.Invalidate(true);
    this.Update();
}
```

---

EDIT: as mentioned in the comments, you could also just invalidate the single child control and update that.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    setText("Prova", new PointF(100, 100));
    this.Controls["ctrId"].Invalidate(true);
    this.Controls["ctrId"].Update();
}
```

Comment: I tested your last code and it works without  (true)

Comment: Thanks to LarsTech and Scott Chamberlain